# Xcode 12. Unable to lookup with an unavailable runtime

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator, xcode12

Unable to boot a simulator in Xcode 12.0 beta.
The simulator is not running only if chosen SwiftUI Project. Automatic preview is not working as well.

[image]

Simulator is running on iOS 14.0.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please file a feedback item with the archive created by `xcrun simctl diagnose` attached and reply with the FB number? We'd like to investigate this further.

Comment: I've opened an issue in Apple Feedback center. Provided them with crash report.
I will update this topic as soon as I get a feedback.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I had the same issue and I just found a solution.

### TL;DR: Quit all running sim and try again, if it still doesn't work, ***delete*** the sim and re-add it.

Actually the detailed message is misleading (which you see by clicking "Details"), it shows:

> Details
>
> Unable to lookup with an unavailable runtime. Domain:
> com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code: 405
> -- The iOS 14.0 simulator runtime is not available. Domain: com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code: 401 Failure Reason: runtime
> path not found Recovery Suggestion: Download the iOS 14.0 simulator
> runtime from the Components section in Xcode's Preferences.
> --
>
> System Information
>
> macOS Version 10.15.5 (Build 19F101) Xcode 12.0 (17177)

At least for me that is what the detailed message says... It suggests that I do not have iOS 14 simulator installed.

Even more confusing was that when I opened Xcode Settings and clicked to `Components` -> `Simulator` I do not see iOS 14 in the list:
[image]

And looking at the existing simulator list next to my Schema it does not explicitly say that the OS of these devices are running iOS 14. [image]

What fixed it for me was to:

1. Make sure to quit any potentially running simulators. This step might be enough? I didn't actually try, I just went straight a head to step 2...
2. Delete a simulator using the "Devices and Simulator Window" - which you can open with shortcut CMD+SHIFT+2 - by right clicking the sim and select "Delete". I used iPhone SE (2nd generation)... After deleting it, then
3. Re-add it, by clicking the plus button in the bottom left corner of the same "Devices and Simulator Window", chose the wanted devices, probably the same you just deleted, and make sure "OS version" is set to 14.
4. Try running again and it works!

Comment: Which os? Are you on Catalina or Big Sur? Im on Catalina

Comment: Catalina 10.15.5.
Main SDK: Xcode 11.4.
Xcode 12.0 as additional.

Comment: I'm in the same boat. Did you find anything else out @Eugene?

Comment: I got an answer from Apple.

Xcode cannot be started from the Downloads folder. To run, macOS will transfer Xcode by copying it to a temporary folder selected at random. Then the folder will disappear from CoreSimulator.

But it's useless.

Comment: Ugh. I hate that this worked lol - though I'm definitely grateful. Thanks! Just quit all sims and tried again. Seems like pretty typical Xcode behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I have MacOs Catalina (10.15.7). Quited Simulator and restarted it again then tried to add new device. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many solutions, but only this one worked.

```
sudo xcrun simctl shutdown all && sudo xcrun simctl erase all
```

[link](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/653807)